# (Spring) JPA/Hibernate strange behaviour

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

im am developing a simple rest application using spring.

I am trying to implement a method that runs periodically using Spring's @Scheduled annotation. 
I had a method to get data from an external api and store it to a databse (Spring Jpa Repositories, extending CrudRepositry).The entities i have are companies and reports (A company has many reports).

The problem im having is this:

To start i was calling that update method from a controller (for easy testing) but now i want to call it from my scheduling class so it executes on its own. But when i move the code (without modifying it) and its called from the shceduler i get this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: Models.Company; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: Models.Company
```

This did not happen when i called the method from the controller and i don't know why it does now.

This is the code im using in both cases:

```
    ReportsManager reportsManager = new ReportsManager();
    reportsManager.updateReports(resultRepository, companyRepository.findAll());
```

Inside the updateReports method i do something like this:

```
    List<BasicReport> resultsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Iterate over the list of companies and create the Report objects:

```
    BasicReport currentResult = new BasicReport();
    currentResult.setReportName(request.getReportName());
    currentResult.setCompany(request.getCompany());
    resultsList.add(currentResult);
```

And then i just save that list elsewhere:

```
    repository.save(currentResults);
```

The werid thing is that i use the EXACT same code in both cases and get a different result.
Any ideas?
Thanks

EDIT: After reading @user152468 comments and @Dries S i added a @Transactional annotation to my scheduler class and its working wonders right now.
I'm guessing the @transactinal annotation binds the EntityManager to the thread. 
Thanks.

Comment: I believe the `@scheduled` annotation does not play well with spring `@transactional` annotation. Spring builds proxies from those classes, and it may not be able to handle both annotations on the same method.

Comment: I am not using the @transactional annotation anywhere though

Comment: it might be implicit if you use @RestController or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If using from a controller you probably have a open-entity-manager-in-view pattern that opens an `EntityManager` for the whole period that your request is running and generating the report.

When running from your scheduled method you probably don't bind the `EntityManager` you use to the current thread and therefore it isn't opened the entire time your method is running and generation the report. Meaning it will open on demand (i.e. in you DAO code) but will close on returning from that method causing entities to be detached.

Try using the [TransactionSynchronisationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html) `bindResource` function which you supply an instance of [EntityManagerHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerHolder.html). Basically what the [OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.java) does, you can look up the source and create a similar approach, it's around line 89.